# .TT file not working as expected in editor

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have installation of VS 2010 SP1 with T4 editing and modelig tools installed problem is that suddenly all icons fro .tt files gone and it has unknown icon. when I open it in VS simple text editor is opened not tengable nothing is working reinstalling extention did not fix the problem. I have notification when I open vs that there are extension updates available and it says that modeling and editing tools update is available. but when I click download button nothing happens. Pleas someone recommend something my projects heavily depend on .tt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that there was a problem with Visual Studio installation so After clean reinstall everything works perfect